# How to filter blog posts by hashtags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to filter blog posts by hashtags.

Which effectively only shows the blog posts with the same id and moves them to the top of the page.

Also a button at the top to show all.

I've tried using this w3 lesson https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_portfolio_gallery_filter

However because it adds display:none, display: block classes, it is interfering with the blog post itself.

Below is the structure of one of the individual blog posts.

```
<div><!--Hide/Show based on what hashtag-->
    <div> <!--Blog Post-->
        <div> <!--Blog Content which also Hide/show-->
            <div>
                <!--blog content 1-->
            </div>
            <div>
                <!--blog content 2-->
            </div>
            <div>
                <!--blog content 3-->
            </div>
            <div><!--blog pagination--></div>
            <div><!--#Hashtag id--></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include all code *relevant* to the question in the quesiton itself. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you share the JavaScript and CSS code as well?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the same boat. Here is the solution:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".filter-id-1").click(function () {
        $(".id-2, .id-3").fadeOut(200);
        $(".id-1").fadeIn(200);
    });
    $(".filter-id-2").click(function () {
        $(".id-1, .id-3").fadeOut(200);
        $(".id-2").fadeIn(200);
    });
    $(".filter-id-3").click(function () {
        $(".id-1, .id-2").fadeOut(200);
        $(".id-3").fadeIn(200);
    });
    $(".filter-all").click(function () {
        $(".id-1, .id-2, .id-3").fadeIn(200);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="filter-all">All</a> <!--Button to filter all-->

<div class="id-1 all">
<div> <!--Blog Post--></div>
<a href="#" class="filter-id-1 id-1 all">Hashtag #id 1</a>
</div>

<div class="id-2 all">
<div> <!--Blog Post--></div>
<a href="#" class="filter-id-2 id-2 all">Hashtag #id 2</a>
</div>

<div class="id-3 all">
<div> <!--Blog Post--></div>
<a href="#" class="filter-id-3 id-3 all">Hashtag #id 3</a>
</div>
```